# Where is pdftk file location folder?

Tags: php, pdftk

I have installed pdftk on my PC that I use for local development using XAMP. I have installed pdftk to my local directory. From the code bellow where should the file test.pdf be placed? I am getting fields.txt created in my websites root directory, but if I place text.pdf there I still get a blank fields.txt file generated. If I go into CMD and CD to my websites root directory and execute the code bellow I get the correct results. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
exec("pdftk test.pdf dump_data_fields > fields.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to restart my PC... Should have known. I thought restarting Apache was enough I was very wrong. Everything works great now.